# Is it a number or letter (Binary Conversion)?

Tags: binary, decimal, ascii, pixel, processor

I just read a lot about how processors work and how everything is just about 0 and 1 but I have a small question.
Suppose the processor got the following input "01100001" how could he know that it's 'a' letter and not the number 97? I don't understand this point and didn't find an answer for it as long as I searched.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do computers differentiate between letters and numbers in binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45103926/how-do-computers-differentiate-between-letters-and-numbers-in-binary)

Comment: Good question. It's possible that you would never know. This is a factor at all levels. For example, if you are given what someone calls a text file, you still wouldn't be able to read it if they didn't tell you which character encoding was used to write it. (ASCII is rarely used for text files; You already know that, right ? If I gave you a text file, I would tell you its character encoding is UTF-8.) If you write a program source file and give it to a compiler or interpreter, how and what are you telling it the character encoding is?

Answer (score 0):

> Suppose the processor got the following input "01100001" how could he
>   know that it's 'a' letter and not the number 97?

Well, generally speaking, the processor doesn't need to know that information, and it is impossible to know how it is going to interpret that input without knowing the architecture and the associated assembly instruction.

> I don't understand this point and didn't find an answer for it as long
>   as I searched.

I think the thing you are missing in your understanding is that the processor is at the lowest layer of [abstraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_layer#Computer_architecture), which is the [hardware level](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_hardware). The processor interacts with memory which is where your example number would reside. What is done with that memory is up to the software. It is also up to the software to determine how to interpret that number when that memory location is read. If you are wondering how a number like that would be printed by a processor, the answer is that it wouldn't. There would be some sort of [peripheral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peripheral) that would be responsible for doing that that the processor is [interfacing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_(computing)) with.

I encourage you to read more about [CPU's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_processing_unit#Structure_and_implementation)